# Dart and Flutter: How can I substitute invisible control characters in a String with e.g. \n?

Tags: dart, flutter

I download an `XML file` in my flutter app and convert it into `Dart Objects` that I later want to serialize with JSON. Since JSON does not accept any invisible carriage return characters, I am looking for a way to substitute those with `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

From your question why don't you use dart String replaceAll method.
With a simple regExp you could replace all the return carriages.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `String` to the [`jsonEncode()` function](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html) from the `dart:convert` library, and it will automatically replace newlines with a `\`, `n` sequence (and will quote the string).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass string to json by using `jsonEncode()` or `jsonDecode()`, and you might declare variable with `var`

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  var string = {
    'a': 'Indication\n',
    'b': 'Indication\t',
    'c': 1
  };

  var enCode = json.encode(string);
  print(enCode); // {"a":Indication\n,"b":Indication\t,"c":1}

  print(jsonDecode(enCode)); // {"a":Indication
                              //    ,"b":Indication  ,"c":3}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone encounters the same issue, I created this little script to remove all control characters from a string.

```
for (final String character in controlCharacters) {
  text = text.replaceAll(character, '');
}
```

And insert this list of control characters somewhere:

```
List<String> controlCharacters = [
  String.fromCharCodes([00]),
  String.fromCharCodes([01]),
  String.fromCharCodes([02]),
  String.fromCharCodes([03]),
  String.fromCharCodes([04]),
  String.fromCharCodes([05]),
  String.fromCharCodes([06]),
  String.fromCharCodes([07]),
  String.fromCharCodes([08]),
  String.fromCharCodes([09]),
  String.fromCharCodes([10]),
  String.fromCharCodes([11]),
  String.fromCharCodes([12]),
  String.fromCharCodes([13]),
  String.fromCharCodes([14]),
  String.fromCharCodes([15]),
  String.fromCharCodes([16]),
  String.fromCharCodes([17]),
  String.fromCharCodes([18]),
  String.fromCharCodes([19]),
  String.fromCharCodes([20]),
  String.fromCharCodes([21]),
  String.fromCharCodes([22]),
  String.fromCharCodes([23]),
  String.fromCharCodes([24]),
  String.fromCharCodes([25]),
  String.fromCharCodes([26]),
  String.fromCharCodes([27]),
  String.fromCharCodes([28]),
  String.fromCharCodes([29]),
  String.fromCharCodes([30]),
  String.fromCharCodes([31]),
];
```

If you wish to read more about control characters, see [this list](https://www.ascii-code.com/characters/control-characters). Do not replace control character 32 as this is your regular space.